# Selenium Shutter Bug Issue - UnableToCompareImagesException

Tags: selenium, image-comparison, selenium-shutterbug

I am getting this error, please help me to resolve this issue.

```
com.assertthat.selenium_shutterbug.utils.image.UnableToCompareImagesException: Images dimensions mismatch: image1 - 2880x1340; image2 - 2880x1362
    at com.assertthat.selenium_shutterbug.utils.image.ImageProcessor.imagesAreEquals(ImageProcessor.java:116)
    at com.assertthat.selenium_shutterbug.core.Snapshot.equals(Snapshot.java:194)
    at com.utilities.BaseFunctions.imageComparison(BaseFunctions.java:826)
    at com.web.consumerscheduling.testcases.CheckScreenShot.regularBookingNewCustomerTC01(CheckScreenShot.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Update the question with your code attempts

Answer (score 0):

The images which you supplied for comparison are having different dimensions which are causing this exception.

**image1 - 2880x1340**
**image2 - 2880x1362**

Please pass the exact same dimension image to avoid this exception.

Comment: Sometimes it is able to compare and I am facing the above issue with the same image